# How to access electronic device using android?

Tags: java, android

i need some ideas for accessing door lock device that mean i want control fingerprint door lock device from my android phone so give me some ideas please.

Comment: That depends on what interfaces your target electronic device provides. for example if they are into network and then you can pass the instructions to it in the form in which it understands from android using `java.net.*` . just an example

Comment: ya we using attendance door lock device with Ethernet

Comment: how to pass my instruction to that device.i don't know which input format. Also how to get finger print from device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is in early stages in Android although many projects have been surface in recent times using Arudino which supports this over USB

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/adk.html

Different examples of arudino can be found over [hackaday.com](http://hackaday.com/category/arduino-hacks/)

Answer (score 0):

I use android for controlling some custom electronic devices. The devices are connected and
controlled from a java application which acts as a device server also listening on a port
for commands from network. What I do is simply sending requests to that server app from
any device android, ios or any device which has network access.